# How can I enable incoming Redis database connections on OpenShift gear?

Tags: redis, openshift

I have tried connecting with

`redis-cli -h $OPENSHIFT_REDIS_HOST -p $OPENSHIFT_REDIS_PORT`

Response is

`Could not connect to Redis at 127.5.216.130:16379: Operation timed out`

Is is necessary to make OpenShift ports open for incoming connections somehow ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you check your firewall?

Comment: Server is definitely running on port 16379. Port is available by listing all environment variables on remote host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the rhc port forward command to open a port directly into your gear over SSH so that you can connect with a local redis client.

You can refer to this section of the developer portal (https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-port-forwarding.html) for more information about how to use it.

Comment: As written in developer portal following command `rhc port-forward -a <app_name>` makes remote port accessible via local address.